# null String when retrieving data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**weird problem:**

This code:

```
xNames[index] = String.valueOf(currentAttendance.getXName());
```

OUTPUT: `"null"`

but this code works fine:

```
xValues[index] = currentAttendance.getxValues();
```

OUTPUT: `7`

any help thank you guys,,,, thank you , I LOVE YOU

this is my snippet code:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

         int count = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
         int[] xValues = new int[count];
         int[] yValues = new int[count];
         String[] xNames = new String[count];

         int index = 0;

         for (DataSnapshot myDatabases : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

             CurrentAttendance cA = myDatabases.getValue(CurrentAttendance.class);

             if (cA != null) {
                xNames[index] = String.valueOf(cA.getXName());
                xValues[index] = cA.getUserCount();
             }

             if (cA != null) {
                yValues[index] = cA.getCurrentAttendance();
             }
             index++
        }

   }
}
```

Database structure:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what is your goal to with valueOf

Comment: There is some problem with `getXName()` of retrieval of values. Do check on these two aspects.

Comment: It can happen when its updating, bcoz you are listening to data change, you might be getting only whats changed :)

Comment: everything is working, `int`, `long` except `String`  @rijin

without valueOf will produce NullPointerException @Comirdc

i am not sure where its problem @PradyumanDixit

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate what data you want to get. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Your question is what i want.

this is my database structure:
`MarketingLine  > Attendance > uid(real uid) > xNames: "Vaianaa"`

i want to retrieve xNames

Comment: Please add your database structure as JSON or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: .. screenshot. Thank you sir
https://ufile.io/7j0mn @AlexMamo

Comment: @vaiana I cannot see any `xNames` property in your database. Can you please be more specifc?

Comment: i am sory sir.. this is correct screenshot. iam hurry.. https://ufile.io/b76op  @AlexMamo

Comment: I suppose the code above not working especially String Value because I try to Retrieve Data of All `Uid` but i am in certain `Uid`. So `String[index]` produce `"null"` .. but i am not sure what the problem is @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Attendance").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String xname = dataSnapshot.child("xname").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, xname);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
Vaianaa
```

To get all the user names, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference attendanceRef = rootRef.child("Attendance");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String xname = ds.child("xname").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, xname);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
attendanceRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
Vaianaa
Newton
```

Comment: So you want to get all user names not only one as in my code above? If so, please see my updated answer.

Comment: oh man, that's what i am searching for.. You really save my day. How should i thank? @AlexMamo